# python program with output in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, export-to-excel

I am trying to write the output retrieved from a large Excel workbook in another spreadsheet using Python. However, I am not able to, it's giving me errors such as raise ValueError("column index (%r) not an int in range(256)" % arg)ValueError: column index (256) not an int in range(256), Exception: Unexpected data type .
I can understand these errors to some extent but not able to rectify my code. I have written a small script here. It will be great if some one can tell me and correct me where I am going wrong.

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')
file_location = "path/lookup_V1.xlsx"
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet1 = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
print sheet1.name
sheet2 = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)
print sheet2.name
print workbook.nsheets
st1c=sheet1.ncols
st2r=sheet2.nrows
st1=st1c+1
st2=st2r+1
print("fill..")  

for i in xrange(0,st1c):
    s1=sheet1.col_values(i)
    i+1
    s1.sort()
    print s1

for col in xrange(st1c):
    for row in xrange(st2r):

    print("filling sheet...")    

    col=col+1
    row=row+1
    ws.write(row,col)
    print("here")
    wb.save('testfile.xls')
```

Comment: Please include the entire traceback so we can see what line it's on. It's no fun having to look back and forth at your error and your code trying to guess when the computer has told you exactly where this occurred and you just didn't share it with us for some reason.

Comment: It would also help if your code was indented properly

Comment: C:\Python2lib\sitepackages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace)"/Testing.py",line 40, in <module>ws.write(row,col)File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1030, in write self.row(r).write(c, label, style)File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 235, in write self.__adjust_bound_col_idx(col File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 78, in_adjust_bound_col_idxraiseValueError("column index (%r) not an int in range(256)" % arg)ValueError: column index (256) not an int in range(256)

Comment: Moving stuff from answer to comment : col and row are index no?

Comment: You can't do st1=st1c+1 since st1c is not defined yet...

Comment: I try your code with a simple excel spreadsheet I create and I realize that you were iterating on col index from sheet 1 and row index from sheet 2, that make no sens...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')
file_location = "test.xls"
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet1 = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
st1c=sheet1.ncols
st1r=sheet1.nrows

for col in xrange(st1c):
    for row in xrange(st1r):
        value = sheet1.col_values(col, row, row + 1)
        # According to documentation : http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Sheet.col_values-method
        # col_values returns a slice of the values of the cells in the given column.
        # That why we have to specify the index below, it is no elegant but it works
        ws.write(row, col, value[0]) 

wb.save('testfile.xls')
```

This solution work for a single sheet... You may then convert it into a function and iterate over different sheets and workbook...

---

More elegant solution :

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')
file_location = "test.xls"
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet1 = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
st1c=sheet1.ncols
st1r=sheet1.nrows

for col in xrange(st1c):
    for row in xrange(st1r):
        # More elegant
        value = sheet1.cell_value(row, col)
        ws.write(row, col, value) 

wb.save('testfile.xls')
```

Comment: I know I am going wrong somewhere, New with Python programming, 
I am just tring to print the values retrieved after sorting sheet 1 I.e s1 into an excel sheet.
The output prints till here and then I believe it goes out of range aise ValueError("column index (%r) not an int in range(256)" % arg)
ValueError: column index (256) not an int in range(256).

Comment: col and row are index I think not cell or value content. So check the doc with this pointer, I am moving right now can help more, I will try later

Comment: Thanks for you help and yes agree row and col are indexes,
I am just trying to post my output retrieved from the code mentioned below into an excel sheet 
for i in xrange(0,st1c):
s1=sheet1.col_values(i)
i+1
s1.sort()
print s1

Comment: Notice you change the index i+1 before the print statement could be the problem

Comment: I changed the index to I+1 so that iterates through all the cells of opened workbook (from where the data is being fetched). 
tried removing the iteration didn't help though

Comment: that was just a typo, it was st1c=sheet1.ncols

Comment: I update the question, after deleting the original and forgot to undeleted once I come up with the solution... Hope it will solve your issue.